# "Software" and "OS Updates"available in Ubuntu Software

Tags: updates, gnome-software

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, on a 64-bit system.

There are two available updates in "Updates" section of the Ubuntu Software, named *OS Updates* and *Software* respectively:

[image: OS Updates]

[image: Software]

I usually update through Software Updater utility, (and occasionally used `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` as recommended by some software installation tutorials)- anything that I think is required. So why is Ubuntu Software showing these updates? Should I install them?

As far as I know, these types of updates, if you look at the list, aren't ever available in the Software Updater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Software does not refresh immediately after you update software from the terminal or using the Software Updater. To test this I updated my software from the terminal using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and then copied the list of packages that were updated. Then I opened Ubuntu Software and saw the same screen as your first screenshot which showed the same two updates were available. When I clicked on OS Updates I saw the same list of packages that I had just finished updating from the terminal. When I clicked the Install button, Ubuntu Software did nothing, but OS Updates disappeared from the center pane.

Because of the confusing delay in showing software updates that have already finished in Ubuntu Software, I recommend updating packages using either the Software Updater app or the terminal instead of Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Exactly right- the "update" and "upgrade" commands are doing the same thing as listed by the Software center!

Answer (score 2):

All three ways  point to the same updates ..
If you start "Software Updater" or do a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in a terminal, you should see exect the same updates as you see in "Software Center".